# $T:V\rightarrow W$ is surjective $\iff \exists S:W\rightarrow V, TS=I_W$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

My textbook has this problem, and I saw some proofs in the net, but this idea seems wrong to me. Can anyone point out where is the loophole in my understanding?

> $T:V\rightarrow W$ is surjective $\iff \exists S:W\rightarrow V, TS=I_W$

My counter example:

Let $V $ be $R^3$, $W$ be $R^2$, and $T$ be the transformation $z=0$. So $T$ maps $3$ dimensional space to $2$ dimensional space $xy$-plane. This mapping is surjective, because for each point in $xy$-plane there is a point in $R^3$. Specifically, for each $(x,y)\in R^2$ all the points in the line parallel to $z$-axis and passing though $(x,y,0)$ in $R^3$ map to $(x,y)$ in $R^2$. So $T$ is surjective here, because range(T) = $R^2$. But since mapping T is not injective, no mapping  $S$ can convert $(x,y)$ in $R^2$ back to $(x,y,z)$ in $R^3$, because we can not decide, to which point of the line, parallel to z-axis, should $(x,y)$ be mapped to.

Comment: "and $T$ be the transformation $z=0$" - can you be more specific? If $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3$, then $T(x,y,z) = ?$

Comment: $T$ maps $(x,y,z)$ to $(x,y,0)$, for all $z$. $T(x,y,z)=(x,y)$

Comment: That's not a map from $\mathbb R^3$ to $\mathbb R^2$. I assume you mean $T(x,y,z) = (x,y)$. In which case, how about $S(x,y) = (x,y,0)$?

Comment: Ok. In that case $TS =I_W$. I was thinking of $ST = I$, which will not be possible to define. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is in

> But since mapping $T$ is not injective, no mapping $S$ can convert $(x,y)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ back to $(x,y,z)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, because we can not decide to which point of the line parallel to $z$-axis, should $(x,y)$ be mapped to.

In a sense, that's precisely what we want to do here — decide which point on this line to map to. Yes, we have infinitely many choices. But it doesn't mean that we can't decide and choose one of them. Of course, this choice can't be random, since we have to come up with a linear transformation. How about we decide that $S$ sends each $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ to $(x,y,0)\in\mathbb{R}^3$? You can verify that this $S$ is indeed a linear transformation and that it satisfies the desired requirements.

I think you may be thinking about finding an inverse to the transformation $t$, which indeed is impossible when $T$ is only surjective but not injective (and thus not bijective). But note that the definition of an inverse requires inverting $T$ from **both** sides. Viz., $S:W\to V$ is an inverse to $T:V\to W$ iff $ST=\operatorname{Id}_V$ **and** $TS=\operatorname{Id}_W$. Of course, that's impossible when $T$ is not bijective. But here we're inverting from the right side only.